# Deleting Radio button using the source code below. i have tried this code all elements get remove except the radio button

Tags: javascript

Below is my code if someone can fixed that will great 
removing radio button is causing problem to my code

```
        <script   src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" > </script>
        <script   src="jquery-1.4.3.js" > </script>



        <h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

        <div id="p_scents">
            <p>
                <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
            </p>

        </div>







        <script>
        var max = 5;

        $(function() {
                var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
                var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

                $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
                    if (i <= max) {
                        $('<p><label for="p_scnts">Age Of  Person ' + i +'<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p><br><p><label for="p_scnts"><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="text1"></textarea></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p><p for="p_scnts[]"><input id="p_scnts" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br><input id="p_scnts" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br><input id="p_scnts" type="radio" name="gender" value="other"></p><a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a>').appendTo(scntDiv);


                        i++;
                        return false;
                    }
                });

                $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
                        if( i > -4 ) {
                                $(this).parents('p').remove();
                                i--;
                        }
                        return false;


                });




        });
```

/* code above is for 3 elements added using java script however removing last radio button is causing problems */

Comment: What "problems" are you having? If we don't know what the problem is, how can we solve it?

Comment: when i try to delete radio button it does not get deleted . button for remove under radio button  would not delete the whole element. can you help me with this. or any code where i can add form elements depending upon how many user one selects.

Comment: Have you looked at your developer's console for error messages?

Comment: It looks like some of your code is missing. This only includes one button to add (and it isnt working)

Comment: yes scott i have checked console could not get whats wrong.button to remove is in script part .please add jquery it will work .

Comment: The size() is deprecated since jquery 1.8. Give us a link to your used jquery file version (jquery < 1.8).

Comment: would that be an easy fix ?

Comment: The easy fix: Can you use the jquery 3.2.1? So that we can test too, because we have 3.2.1. Version 1.4.3 is too old.

Comment: you can use 3.2.1 it wil work use  any version. now it would be helpful ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var max = 5;
var i = 1;

$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');

  $('#addScnt').on('click', function() {
    if (i < max + 1) {
      $('<div class="person"><p><label for="p_scnts">Age Of  Person ' + i +'<input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label></p><br><p><label for="p_scnts"><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="text1"></textarea></label></p><p for="p_scnts[]"><input id="p_scnts" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br><input id="p_scnts" type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br><input id="p_scnts" type="radio" name="gender" value="other">Other<br><a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p></div>').appendTo(scntDiv);

      i++;
      $('.remScnt').on('click', function() { 
        $(this).parents('div.person').remove();
        i--;
        return false;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

        <div id="p_scents">
            <p>
                <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
            </p>

        </div>
```

I have made some changes, and this seems to work for me.

I removed your reference to `size()` because it didn't seem necessary

Comment: i hope one problem there if that can be fixed i need only 5 people counter as i delete and add another box it starts with -57 or some number. could it be like a proper counter . i got what that problem thanks

Comment: Updated the answer and the preview

Comment: There is no need to post "preview" code at 3rd party sites. Just include a code snippet right here in your answer.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I didn't know about this feature

Comment: counter should be starting zero if all 5 elements deleted . or something dynamic example element 4 is deleted then element 5 should change to 4 and adding after words would create element 5.

Comment: I will leave this for you to develop yourself as I have already done quite a lot of work for you. And this seems to be a different question to the one originally asked

Comment: ok thanks i have been  working this for long time i have been trying 50 plus code files however i will try to reset the counter